# What does #[skip_meta] do?

Tags: benchmarking

I notice some benchmarks in Frame have #[skip_meta].

What does this macro do?

Please explain when one should use this macro when benchmarking.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I found.

https://github.dev/paritytech/substrate/blob/15cfd9c5dbbfa1f3ed49623eb55b67354d1645e9/frame/benchmarking/src/lib.rs#L1109-L1115

https://github.dev/paritytech/substrate/blob/15cfd9c5dbbfa1f3ed49623eb55b67354d1645e9/primitives/externalities/src/lib.rs#L306-L311

It would ignore the `reads_and_writes` if the benchmark was marked as `#[skip_meta]`.

It won't calculate the `reads_and_writes` and won't put them into the `BenchmarkResult`.

Comment: ahh nice find. I wonder why we would want to ignore the read and writes?